# Difference search result for BING API vs BING.COM

Tags: api, search, bing

Anyone know why the search result for normal bing.com and bing api 2.2 is different?

Example:

http://api.search.live.net/xml.aspx?Appid=yourid&query=aggregate+study+site%3Awww.sandag.org&sources=web

and

http://www.bing.com/search?q=aggregate+study+site%3Awww.sandag.org

Returns completely different results.

Comment: Obviously, bing.com is not using it's own 2.2 API. I would be surprised if they used their own API at all, I am willing to bet it does it's own thing which they try to keep paralleled with the API.

Comment: Bing.COM's Result are much better then the API. I guess that's what you get for free...

Answer (score 3):

It is the market parameter. Check it.
Bing specifies the market parameter based on your IP , and your cookies and browsing history.